# How to identify the User running the application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to check in the code how to identify the User running the application, I want to make sure the domain user I defined in IIS is applied

thanks

Comment: You mean the user that runs the app pool ? Or the user that views the webpage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this before, try if it works for you

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: it worked great. Do you have to know if I can set this up in web.config instead of IIS?

Comment: This was handy for me in a terminal services scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need: [HttpContext.Current.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) or get access to the HTTP context from the controller.

Comment: there is no .Current from HttpContext in the Controller,

Comment: Current is a static on the HttpContext class itself.

Comment: for MVC the Controller contains HttpContext which is  System.Web.HttpContextWrapper, which there is no current.user. What you meant is the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User which the name returns empty. The System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name works fine. Thanks for your answer, +1, it will help elucidate next users who want to get same information